ESP32lan board - problem with LAN8720 - ESP32 does not get ip address from dhcp
I have a problem with ESPlan board (https://github.com/LaskaKit/ESPlan).
= ESP32 POE LAN8720 board.
It was working fine with my simple modbus application which read some inputs and post it on modbus server and on an mqqt server. When i did upload a new code yesterday which counted some changes of the inputs, the ethernet communication stopped working.
So I tried the old code, it didn't work either.
After that I tried to run a simple ethernet connection code with or without static IP setting, didn't help at all.
So I started searching the Internet about this issue and found multiple different articles, threads about problems with LAN8720 chips:
https://www.olimex.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=16s2u62d77d3q5tlagapmiog6a&topic=7099.15
https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=29070&start=10
https://www.crowdsupply.com/silicognition/wesp32/updates/the-phy-reset-saga
https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=17802
My question is, is it even reasonable to use such product, if the chip it self is not reliable? Or is there a simple way I can reset the configuration of the LAN8720 chip or something?
PS: simple way = uses platformio and standard arduino libraries <Arduino.h> <ETH.h>
The Ethernet test code:
#include <Arduino.h>
#define ETH_POWER_PIN -1
#define ETH_ADDR 0
#define ETH_MDC_PIN 23
#define ETH_MDIO_PIN 18
#define ETH_NRST_PIN 5
#include <ETH.h>

bool eth_connected = false;

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event)
{
    switch (event)
    {
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_START:
        Serial.println("ETH Started");
        // set eth hostname here
        ETH.setHostname("esplan");
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_CONNECTED:
        Serial.println("ETH Connected");
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP:
        Serial.print("ETH MAC: ");
        Serial.print(ETH.macAddress());
        Serial.print(", IPv4: ");
        Serial.print(ETH.localIP());
        if (ETH.fullDuplex())
        {
            Serial.print(", FULL_DUPLEX");
        }
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(ETH.linkSpeed());
        Serial.println("Mbps");
        eth_connected = true;
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_DISCONNECTED:
        Serial.println("ETH Disconnected");
        eth_connected = false;
        break;
    case ARDUINO_EVENT_ETH_STOP:
        Serial.println("ETH Stopped");
        eth_connected = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // For reseting LAN8720A
  pinMode(ETH_NRST_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ETH_NRST_PIN, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ETH_NRST_PIN, HIGH);

  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);

  ETH.begin(ETH_ADDR, ETH_POWER_PIN, ETH_MDC_PIN, ETH_MDIO_PIN, ETH_PHY_LAN8720, ETH_CLOCK_GPIO17_OUT);

  
  
  Serial.println("ETH Started");
  Serial.println("IP address: " + ETH.localIP().toString());
  Serial.println("ETH MAC: " + ETH.macAddress());
  Serial.println("ETH Link Speed: " + String(ETH.linkSpeed()) + "Mbps");
  Serial.println("ETH Full Duplex: " + String(ETH.fullDuplex() ? "true" : "false"));
  Serial.println("ETH Link Status: " + String(ETH.linkUp() ? "connected" : "disconnected"));
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

Serial output of the code above:
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
ETH Started
ETH Started
IP address: 0.0.0.0
ETH MAC: 70:B8:F6:XX:XX:XX
ETH Link Speed: 10Mbps
ETH Full Duplex: false
ETH Link Status: disconnected

